# unable to get fancybox to work - opens in new window

Tags: fancybox

I have been trying to get fancybox to work in this free template that a nice guy gave away on reddit yesterday but I'm not having much luck. I'm decent with HTML/CSS but not too great at Jquery. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I'm trying to get the portfolio images to pop up in fancyboxes.  http://jsfiddle.net/yz93H/1/  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
   });
    </script>


   <figure class="entry web"> 
                <a class="fancybox" href="img/portfolio-image.jpg"><img src="img/portfolio-image.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsfiddle you posted is a little bit difficult to work with due to all the relative paths, still, one thing I noticed is that you're not linking the Fancybox javascript into your document.

There should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>`
```

Hopefully that will fix it.

**EDIT**: Sorry, missed your js at the end of the document. On a second look, I found your problem. The snippet you posted should come **after** jQuery has been loaded. Since your jQuery is only loaded at the end of the document, your code was throwing `Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`.

I've created a new fiddle with a working version of what you posted. Everything is loaded off CDN's and I've used Twitter's logo as a showcase: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoespinha/yz93H/4/

Essentially, the only change you need is to put this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

after jQuery's script tag.

Comment: thanks for the reply. If you look at the bottom fancybox is linked already :/. Sorry its hard to read. So basically I've got the script calling fancybox function in the head, the image I am trying to use in the middle (portfolio section), and the link to fancybox.js at the bottom. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but I've tried every other way I can think of with no luck. The images are not in divs but the figure tags which I am not familiar with, not sure if this is affecting things. I am just trying to get the absolute simplest form of fancybox to work. Thanks again

Comment: You're right. I missed your js code at the end. I've fixed my answer now, hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I should have  checked firebug for errors and I may have figured it out.  You're awesome! I'd up vote you if I could. Thanks again I get stuck on little things like this and just sit there pulling my hair out. Have a great weekend

Comment: Perfectly normal! It's these small problems that result in the biggest headaches. Glad I could help!